# 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

Getting this error for the orderby in where clause.  I did this because previously, if I didn't define 'people' I'd get an error on the return for people saying the name 'people' doesnt exist in this current context.  How do I fix this?

```
 public JsonResult PersonsList(string birthyear)
 {
     TutorialDBContext db = new TutorialDBContext();
     var NumericYear = Convert.ToInt32(birthyear);
     IQueryable people;

     if (birthyear == "All")
     {
          people = from m in db.persons
                   select m;

          people = people.OrderByDescending(s => s.birthdate);
     }
     else
     {
          people = from m in db.persons
                   where m.birthdate.Year >= NumericYear
                   where m.birthdate.Year <= (NumericYear + 9)
                   select m;
     }

     return Json(people, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is indeed no such method. There is one on that accepts an `IQueryable<T>` though. Use

```
IQueryable<Person> people;
```

or whatever element type would be appropriate.

Comment: The perils of being a noob. Thanks man, also its perons, not Person

Comment: Why have it as "perons"? If nothing else, capital letters for type names is more idiomatic in .Net.

Comment: Typo, meant "persons".  I created the persons table in sql, and entity framework kept the casing.  I agree on idiomatic part, this is just a sample project i'm hoping to help my new developer friends with.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the name of the entity to `Person`, and `Persons` (or `People` would be reasonable) for the name of the property that access them. The individual entity does after all presumably represent a single person. (If anything, a sample project for anyone's use other than just yourself should be more pernickety about such minor things, as samples should encourage good practices in those looking at them as much as possible).

Comment: So you suggest simply changing the db table and then updating EF in solution?

Comment: No, I'd edit the EDMX file if one was used, or just adding the appropriate `[Table]` attribute otherwise, so that the table names are lowercase and plural but the C# class names are initial-capital and singular.

Answer (score 5):

[`OrderByDescending()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534316(v=vs.110).aspx) is an extension method of **`IQueryable<T>`**, not of the non-generic `IQueryable`.

So you need to declare `people` as `IQueryable<Person>`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't downvote, but `OrderByDescending` is _also_ an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`, though that nit pick is not a reason for a downvote in my opinion.

Comment: I upvoted all answers. Now my question is also downvoted :x

Comment: @DStaney [yes, really](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx). I guess overload resolution will select the most derived one though, in this case indeed the `IQueryable<T>` one.

Comment: @CodeCaster The variable is of type `IQueryable<T>`. When looking for `OrderByEnumerable`, the compiler will find the extension method of `IQueryable<T>` _before_ the extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` because extension methods on the declared type will be chosen before extension methods on derived type(s).

Comment: @DStanley of course, you're right (in the comments under your answer as well). Thanks. Seems like I forgot about the existence of `IQueryable<T>` and its extension methods altogether...

Comment: @CodeCaster Not a problem - wasn't meant to be a criticism, just a clarification.  +1

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned several times you'd need to declare `people` as an `IQueryable<Person>` or whatever the type returned from the `People` table is.  If you want to use implicit typing you could rearrange your code as so:

```
var people = from m in db.persons
             select m;
if (birthyear == "All")
{
    people = people.OrderByDescending(s => s.birthdate);
}
else
{
     people = people.Where(p => p.birthdate.Year >= NumericYear
                             && p.birthdate.Year <= NumericYear + 9)
}
```

Comment: Will that compile though? Won't `from m select m` return an `IQueryable<T>`, to which you cannot assign an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Actually it [returns an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx) which [extends `IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340178(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can assign it to a variable of such,

Answer (score 1):

1. You must have `using System.Linq;` at the begining of the code file.
2. You should change `IQueryable people;` to `IQueryable<Person> people;`
3. If you call this method with `All` as `birthyear` value you will get an exception when you reach `var NumericYear = Convert.ToInt32(birthyear);`
4. I suggest to change the whole function to this

   ```
   public JsonResult PersonsList(string birthyear)
   {
       using (var db = new TutorialDBContext())
       {
           IQueryable<Person> people;

           if (birthyear == "All")
           {
               people = db.persons.OrderByDescending(s => s.birthdate);
           }
           else
           {
               var NumericYear = Convert.ToInt32(birthyear);
               people = from m in db.persons
                   where m.birthdate.Year >= NumericYear
                   where m.birthdate.Year <= (NumericYear + 9)
                   select m;
           }

           return Json(people, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
   }
   ```